# python manipulating list after user input

Tags: python

```
months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
usermonth=input('Enter the month: ')
if usermonth >=months[0]and usermonth <=months[10]:
   nextmonth=months(usermonth+1)
   print(nextmonth)
```

How would I go about defining one up in the index of the user's month?
Thanks.

Comment: What does "defining one up in the index of the user's month" mean? What are you trying to achieve, and what is going wrong?

Comment: I wonder if the answer is along the lines of months[(usermonth + 1) % 11] but it's far to vague to work out what the expected input is since it's used as a string comparison and then (ignoring treating months like a function) as an array index.

Comment: Why are you comparing? What should the user input? a month name or number?

Comment: sorry haha I can see why that's confusing, the program needs to tell the user what month it will be after the inputted month.

Comment: You can just do months[months.index(usermonth)+1]

Comment: Provided user should enter valid month as mentioned in the list

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to display the month after the one supplied by the user:

```
 months.index(usermonth)
```

will give you the index (in the months list) of the months supplied by the user.

Then you can test if your month's index is not above 11:

```
months=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']
usermonth=input('Enter the month: ')
if months.index(usermonth) < 11:
   print(months[months.index(usermonth) + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to print the next month, inserted by the user :

To do this, you need to have a better understanding of **arrays**, and **indexing** (or, said differently : how to access a list of data).

You properly used the indexing in your if-statement, but, you didn't in the line  trying to define `nextMonth`. Doing `months()` called the keyword `months` as if it is a function : and you need to call it as a list, and therefore, use an **index**, with `[]`. :)